# Getting the name of the program sending notifications

Tags: linux, bash, notifications

I'm trying to get Dunst to make different sounds when different applications send notifications. Dunst uses a script to play a sound when it gets a notification, this is what is currently in mine:

```
#!/bin/sh
paplay ~/.config/dunst/notification.ogg
```

My idea was to use an if statement checking for the name of the application to select which sound is played, something like

```
#!/bin/sh
if(application1)
then
    paplay ~/.config/dunst/notification1.ogg
elif(application2)
then
    paplay ~/.config/dunst/notification2.ogg
else
    paplay ~/.config/dunst/notification3.ogg
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dunst-project.org/documentation/), when you call scripts from a rules file, your [script has access to a few environment variables](https://dunst-project.org/documentation/#SCRIPTING). Or you can give them directly as arguments to the script you are calling.

So I guess what you want in your script is something like

```bsh
if [ "$DUNST_APP_NAME" = "application1" ]; then
    #...
elif [ ... ]
    #...
#...
fi
```